# Aptana Studio Black IBeam Cursor on Dark Background

Tags: ubuntu, aptana

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with Aptana Studio 3.0.8 the problem is i can't change black/dark ibeam cursor to white/light. dark ibeam very annoying for me since i use dark background color.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the exactly same issue.  It's really stupid that the cursor is very thick that it's BLOCKING my text!

Comment: i am trying to figure it out last month, and this is happen only when i use onboard vga (via chipset)

Comment: @pengemizt You forgot to ask the question!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you want to make sure you can use a custom cursor (they use the term 'caret' in the Preferences) by going to your `Preferences -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Accessibility` and then check "Use custom caret"

Then whichever color scheme you're using, there should be a color select box at the top for "Caret"